# Xcode - UIActivityIndicator disappears too soon

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pdf, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an UIActivityIndicator that should loop until a PDF file is loading.

I can't understand why, but the indicator disappears before the PDF is loaded.
I can't understand if the PDF file is too large (1,4 MB), if my app freezes, or if I wrote something wrong in the code

```
-(void)startTheProcess {

    act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    //coordinate act
    [act setCenter:CGPointMake(320 / 2, 440 / 2)];
    self.act.hidden = FALSE;
    [self.view addSubview:act];
    [act startAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(creaVista) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) creaVista{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.something.com/file.pdf"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [pdfView loadRequest:request];
    [pdfView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processDone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}
-(void)processDone {

    [act stopAnimating];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
}
```

If I debug it, I can easily see that the debugger goes quickly to `[act stopAnimating]` and then stops, but the file is not yet loaded: after a few seconds the PDF appears.

Have you got any hints? I'm a noob and I think I'm doing some foolish mistakes...
Thanks

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but maybe `[pdfView loadRequest:request]` is an asynchronous operation and so it returns immediately and calls `[act stopAnimating]`. Also, you have it trying to stop the animation in both `createVista:` and when you call `processDone:` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, copying error.
in creaVista I do not stop the act...

Comment: Is your pdfView on top of your activity indicator in the view layer hierarchy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like Joshua has the right idea in the comments. The load is asynchronous and will return before the load is actually done.

If your `pdfView` is a UIWebView you can use the [`UIWebViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method `webViewDidFinishLoad:` to know when the PDF is done loading. If you place your `[act stopAnimating]` in there it should work.

You would also want to place it in `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` incase there are any errors.

To set the delegate on the `pdfView` do this: `[pdfView setDelegate:self];` 
and make sure that you have your controller adopt the `UIWebViewDelegate` like this:
`@interface ClassName : ItsSuperclass < UIWebViewDelegate >`

Comment: Great! It works perfectly and the UIActivityIndicator disappears just before the PDF indicator is shown!